# Python / Django - How do I alter a variable inside the template?

Tags: python, django, variables, django-templates

I have an variable that I need to alter inside the template.

Let's say the variable `foo` is `4`, but I need the value to be `foo + 1`.

I'll then use this in an `if` statement, like so:

```
{% if bar == foo+1 %}
<p>Condition has been met!</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You could do it by writing a templatetag but you really don't want to do this. Django's template design is purposely limited as they encourage logic to be placed in views instead.

Comment: Could you please tell what are you trying to accomplish? Maybe we could suggest a more elegant way

Comment: @super9 while I agree with this sentiment, there are times when unusual layouts require slightly complicated template logic (multiple  columns etc.) : This isn't logic relevant to the view - it's display logic and therefore should stay in the template (imo)

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony Absolutely. Guidelines are guidelines, not dogma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
{% if bar == foo|add:1 %}
<p>Condition has been met!</p>
{% endif %}
```

Or another is:

```
{%with newfoo=foo|add:1 %}
  {% if bar == newfoo %}
  <p>Condition has been met!</p>
  {% endif %}
{%endwith%}
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer based on a situation where you feel that you really need to change a variable in a template. However, as super9 suggested in the comments above, it's best to try and do this in the views first.

Comment: @Owen Agree, logic shouldn't be put in template, view is for that.

Answer (score 4):

Your code will be more transparent and "djangoic" if you keep the logic in the views and not in the templates. So instead of calculating `foo+1` in the template, pass the template a boolean variable called `foo_equals_bar`, or pass it variables `bar` and `foo_incremented` then compare those.

Look how much more readable it is:

```
{% if foo_equals_bar %}
<p>Condition has been met!</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% with foo|add:"1" as foo1 %}
{% if foo1 ==  bar %}
<p>....</p>
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```